How to generate vanity keypairs in typescript
Is there a way to generate vanity keypairs using Typescript apart from using the generate method and matching the prefix/suffix of generated keypairs
const keypair = Keypair.generate();
while (true) {
    if (keypair.publicKey.toBase58().startsWith(prefix)) break;
}

Also, I'd love a solution that does not involve web workers.

Your solution seems great -- what is the problem exactly?

No problem. I was just wondering if there was a better/faster way of doing it.

To generate a vanity keypair in TypeScript, you can use a brute-force loop that repeatedly generates keypairs and checks if the public key matches the desired pattern.
import { Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';  

function generateVanityKeypair(prefix: string): Keypair {  
  let keypair: Keypair;  
  do {  
    keypair = Keypair.generate();  
  } while (!keypair.publicKey.toBase58().startsWith(prefix));  
  return keypair;  
}  

// Example usage  
const prefix = 'abc'; // Desired prefix  
const vanityKeypair = generateVanityKeypair(prefix);  

console.log('Vanity Public Key:', vanityKeypair.publicKey.toBase58());  
console.log('Private Key:', Buffer.from(vanityKeypair.secretKey).toString('hex'));


Thank you for the answer but in my question I am seeking an alternative?
